# SuiteCRM - Multiple server setup

Tags: mysql, apache2, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Looking to confirm the last bit regarding DMZ.

Servers as follows:
 - 1 x Ubuntu Server 16.02 - Internal MYSQL SERVER
 - 1 X Ubuntu Server 16.02 - Internal Only Apache2 Webserver,
 - 1 x Ubuntu Server 16.02 - Sat in DMZ for access via vpn/mobile clients.

We have 2 instances of Suite running, a live system and a development system. 
each with its own MYSQL DB.
The MYSQL Server is currently internal but with various security lock downs in place for specific access only from both webservers only.

SuiteCRM Internally all fine but I am concerned then when I come to do the external Web Server that the URL for Suite is embedded into the mysql db and that I will have problems.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what do you mean by  
*URL for Suite is embedded into the mysql db*

Comment: Sorry, I thought form looking in admin panel URL for web server was embeded into DB.  Turns out the big issue was my incorrect Apache config.  All now working fine thanks...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above.  This setup is now all working as I described above.

I had 2 issues, 1 was an incorrect Apache site/host config and the second was file permissions from the working copied website to the DMZ machine.

After I updated permissions as per the SuiteCRM site, all worked fine.